# I'm having this issue: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matricula')

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to put data into a database through a formulary using Handlebars as a view engine, it happens that this error message appears when I click the button to send the data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matricula').

This is my migration file creating the "Alunos" table:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   return queryInterface.createTable('alunos', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    matricula: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    nome: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    curso: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ano: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
   });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   return queryInterface.dropTable('alunos');
  }
};
```

This is the Aluno's model:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/sequelize');

const Aluno = sequelize.define('alunos', {
    matricula: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    nome: DataTypes.STRING,
    curso: DataTypes.STRING,
    ano: DataTypes.INTEGER,
});

module.exports = Aluno;
```

This is the config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'novoProjeto',
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
  },
};
```

This is the sequelize.js file:

```
const database = require('./config');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database);

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
    //message if connects
    console.log('Conexão executada com o banco de dados.')
}).catch(function(err){
    //message if it doesn't
    console.log('Conexão não executada com o banco de dados devido a: ' + err)
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

This is the index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.use(routes);

//Config
    //Template Config
    app.engine('handlebars', engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    //Body Parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000);
```

This is the routes.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();

const AlunoController = require('../Controller/AlunoController');

//Home page
    routes.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.send('Home page')
    });

// Routes for Aluno's data
    //Final register page
    routes.post('/add-aluno', function(req, res){
        //This is where the error goes
        res.send(`Data sent. Matricula: ${req.body.matricula} ;Nome: ${req.body.nome}; Curso: ${req.body.curso}; Ano: ${req.body.ano}`)
    });
    //Mostrar alunos cadastrados
    routes.get('/show-alunos', function(req, res){
        AlunoController.index
    });
    //Atualizar dados de aluno específico
    routes.put('/upd-aluno/:id', function(req, res){
        AlunoController.put
    });
    //Deletar dados de aluno específico
    routes.delete('/del-aluno/:id', function(req, res){
        AlunoController.delete
    });

    //Rota para formulário de cadastro de alunos
    routes.get('/cad-aluno', function(req, res){
        res.render('formulario')
    });
   

module.exports = routes;
```

And this is the form.handlebars file:

```
<form action="/add-aluno" method="post">
<label>Matrícula: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="matricula" placeholder="Ex.: 0001122">
<br>
<label>Nome: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Ex.: João Guilherme...">
<br>
<label>Curso: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="curso" placeholder="Ex.: Enfermagem">
<br>
<label>Ano: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="ano" placeholder="Ex.: 2">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

I don't know what can I do here. The main error is in the routes.js file. Before sending the data to the database, I try to send a message showing the 4 informations in the fields, being these: Matricula, Nome, Curso, Ano. But it doesn't show nothing because it says it's undefined. Can someone help?

Some //comments are in portuguese, I translated the ones you should read just to facilitate.

Comment: It seems that the request body is already undefined (i.e. ```request.body``` is ```undefined```). Thus it tries to read the property ```matricula``` from ```undefined```, which results in your ```TypeError```. I would suggest you use the DevTools of your browser (try F12) to further evaluate how your data is sent. I guess the problem is either in how the frontend forms the request (i.e. where and how it puts your inputs) or how your backend tries to interpret the request (it looks like it expects a JSON body or URL encoded form body). The backend logic itself looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file you have the `app.use(routes)` line before the `app.use(bodyParser.json())` line. In order for express to extract data from the request body, it needs to have previously passed through the bodyParser middlewear. If you move the `app.use(routes)` line just before the `app.listen(3000)` it should work.

Also, as a side note, you don't need to install the bodyParser library anymore, as it's build into Express now. You could replace the following lines:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

with this instead:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
```